# Installing to a MySQL database that requires SSL

Tags: database, 9, installation, ssl

I am attempting to install Drupal 9 to a fresh host using an AWS MySQL RDS instance for a database.  The database is configured to require SSL. When attempting to install via the web GUI, I receive `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [3159] Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON`, which indicates that Drupal is attempting to connect without using SSL and that is working as one would expect. I have added the database config, including the appropriate PDO options for SSL, to settings.php but this causes a number of "unmet dependencies" errors that I believe stem from Drupal thinking that the database is already installed.  I can connect to the db from the host in both the MySQL CLI and PHP, so I know the connection can work.  How can I get Drupal to send its database test connection using SSL (or more generally, any driver specific options?)

EDIT: Looks like after adding the creds to settings.php, it did create some tables.  However, the installation won't complete due to the below error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException: Configuration objects provided by <em class="placeholder">standard</em> have unmet dependencies: <em class="placeholder">block.block.bartik_account_menu (block, bartik), block.block.bartik_help (help, block, bartik), block.block.bartik_local_actions (bartik, block), block.block.bartik_search (search, block, bartik), block.block.seven_breadcrumbs (block), block.block.seven_help (help, block), block_content.type.basic (block_content), comment.type.comment (comment), contact.form.feedback (contact), core.entity_form_display.block_content.basic.default (text), core.entity_form_display.node.article.default (image.style.thumbnail, comment, image, path, text), core.entity_form_display.node.page.default (path, text), core.entity_form_display.user.user.default (image.style.thumbnail, image), core.entity_view_display.node.article.default (image.style.large, comment, image, text), core.entity_view_display.node.article.rss (core.entity_view_mode.node.rss), core.entity_view_display.node.article.teaser (core.entity_view_mode.node.teaser, image.style.medium, image, text), core.entity_view_display.node.page.teaser (core.entity_view_mode.node.teaser, text), editor.editor.basic_html (ckeditor, editor), field.field.block_content.basic.body (field.storage.block_content.body, text, field), field.field.comment.comment.comment_body (field.storage.comment.comment_body, text, field), field.field.node.article.body (field.storage.node.body, text, field), field.field.node.article.comment (comment, field), field.field.node.article.field_image (image, field), field.field.node.article.field_tags (field), field.storage.node.comment (comment, node, field), field.storage.node.field_image (file, image, node, field), field.storage.node.field_tags (node, taxonomy, field), field.storage.user.user_picture (file, image, field), filter.format.basic_html (editor, filter), filter.format.restricted_html (filter), node.type.article (node), rdf.mapping.comment.comment (comment, rdf), rdf.mapping.node.article (node, rdf), rdf.mapping.taxonomy_term.tags (taxonomy, rdf), taxonomy.vocabulary.tags (taxonomy), user.role.anonymous (comment, contact, filter, search), user.role.authenticated (comment, contact, filter, search, shortcut), user.role.content_editor (comment, contextual, file, node, path, taxonomy, toolbar, tour)</em> in Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create() (line 100 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/UnmetDependenciesException.php).
Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create() (Line: 530)
Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall() (Line: 132)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall() (Line: 196)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install() (Line: 83)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install() (Line: 1658)
install_install_profile() (Line: 700)
install_run_task() (Line: 571)
install_run_tasks() (Line: 119)
install_drupal() (Line: 48)
```

Comment: The "unmet dependencies" thing sounds as if the MySQL max_allowed_packet setting hasn't been properly set for Drupal.

Comment: Looks like max_allowed_packet is the default 64M, which worked properly for me on a similar install.  Apache logs don't show anything more verbose than what is output to the display and the watchdog table was NOT created.

Comment: The "unmet dependencies" is a bit of a classic and in the past has been max_allowed_packet set too low. The error would actually be logged by the database instance, depending on its logging level.